Obtain the row exchanges required to solve the following linear systems using Algorithm 6.2
Obtain the row exchanges required to solve the following linear systems using Algorithm 6.2 (Burden & Faires Textbook. Gaussian Elimination with Partial Pivot).
(to)
$\begin{array}{r}
{x_1-5x_2+x_3=8}\\
{10x_1+20x_3=6}\\
{5x_1-x_3=4}\\
\end{array}$
(b)
$\begin{array}{r}
{2x_1-3x_2+2x_3=8}\\
{-4x_1+2x_2-6x_3=14}\\
{2x_1+2x_2+4x_3=8}\\
\end{array}$
Partial pivoting consists of taking the one with the absolute greatest as the pivot in each column.
For $x_1$ the largest coefficient is $10$ then the order of the first and second equations changes:
$\begin{array}{r}
{10x_1+20x_3=6}\\
{x_1-5x_2+x_3=8}\\
{5x_1-x_3=4}\\
\end{matrix}$
Then subtract the first equation between $10$ from the second and the first between two from the third:
$\begin{array}{r}
{10x_1+20x_3=6}\\
{-5x_2-x_3=37/5}\\
{-11x_3=1}\\
\end{matrix}$
Is correct?
How is part b) with partial pivoting? I tried to solve it but I got confused when doing the operations
